# AngularJS directive with Complexify

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need help to create a `AngularJS` directive with [Complexify](http://danpalmer.me/jquery-complexify/). It's a password meter. I needed this:

```
<input type="password" ng-model="password" />
<password-meter value="password" complexity="complexity"></passwordMeter>
<span class="label label-important" ng-show="complexity > 60">STRONG</span>
```

In my example, when password complexity is high, my `<span>` is display.

My code:

```
app.directive('passwordMeter', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var minLengthPassword = 6;
        var strengthScaleFactor = 1;

        $(element).complexify({
          minimumChars: minLengthPassword,
          strengthScaleFactor: strengthScaleFactor
        }, function(valid, complexity) {
          if(valid) {
            scope.complexity = complexity;
          } else {
            scope.complexity = 0;
          }
        });

        scope.$watch('password', function() {
          if(!scope.password) {
            scope.complexity = 0;
          }
        });
      }
    };
});
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: forgot to outline what your problem is. I see an explanation, some apparently valid code.... but no detail as to what's not working or what errors occur

Comment: not sure what `complexity` attribute should be used for... but it's not being passed to scope of directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some errors you need to fix:

1. If you define a directive name which is camel-case (passwordMeter) it maps to password-meter in your templates
2. To use the directive as an element like you do  you need to set restrict: 'E' and not 'A'
3. jquery-complexify works on inputs so you need to include the input you define outside the password-meter directive inside your directive and reference it.

I've created a working plunker for you http://plnkr.co/edit/PdK8U7q3GzWVVUX5alrS?p=preview